# Remove Keepass2 icon from system tray?

Tags: ubuntu

Since the upgrade to ubuntu 22.04, keepass2 shows an annoying icon in my system tray.
Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: Are you talking about [KeePass 2.x](https://keepass.info/index.html) as in your question, [KeePassX](https://www.keepassx.org/) as in your tags, or perhaps [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/)?

Comment: It is KeePass2 (removed erroneous tag, thanks for pointing me out)

Comment: Consider using KeePassXC. Keepass 2 is basically a Windows only application (written in C#).

Comment: Are the two compatible, including interface with firefox plugins?